# Echo every record selected in this session

Tags: php, arrays, yii

This is my code in controller.php

```
if(!isset(Yii::app()->session['cart_values'])) {
            Yii::app()->session['cart_values'] = array();
        }

$sessionCart = array();

$sessionCart[] = array('product_id' => Yii::app()->session['productID'], 'document' => Yii::app()->session['productName']);
Yii::app()->session['cart_values'] = $sessionCart;
```

My problem is that when I try to echo the result I got only the last record that I have selected, but what I need is every record selected in this session. I know that i need to make a check before I start to filing the array, but not sure how.

```
  <?php
    if (is_array(Yii::app()->session['cart_values']))
{
    foreach ( Yii::app()->session['cart_values'] as $value) {

    echo $value['document'];
}
}
    ?>
```

I want to understand it by my own, but i'm confused,so if anybody could help me I would be very happy. Thanks.
P.S. Sorry for my English, i hope everybody understands me.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I get my solution by my own, thanks everybody, so my controller php script should look like this.

```
if(!isset(Yii::app()->session['cart_values'])) {
            Yii::app()->session['cart_values'] = array();
        } else {
            $sessionCart = Yii::app()->session['cart_values'];

            $sessionCart[] = array('product_id' => Yii::app()->session['productID'], 'document' => Yii::app()->session['productName']);

            Yii::app()->session['cart_values'] = $sessionCart;

        }
```

Comment: What is your problem? You want to insert unique product in cart_values session array? OR you are getting only the last inserted product array in session variable cart_values?

Comment: I am getting only the last selected product array in session variable cart_values.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Yii::app()->session['cart_values'][] = $sessionCart;
```

Comment: No Ivo, that doesn't help me, I got the next error "Indirect modification of overloaded element of CDbHttpSession has no effect"